# Procedure to find certain images in a CSS sprite?

Tags: css

Is there a correct procedure to locate certain image locations in an image sprite. Say I wanted to create 10 div images in my header using the image below, how do I find the precise location of each.

Is just a case of trial and error using CSS background position till the image fits?

http://www.argos.co.uk/wcsstore/argos/en_GB/siteAssets/brfp-2014/images/icons-s73f662fc84.png

Comment: You open it in an image editor and start measuring. Normally you create this image and so you know where everything is put.

Comment: Usually the person making the image will know this, and may provide some documentation to go with it. I can't imagine a procedure existing for this purpose, since it would require a huge comprehension of what the various sprites mean. If you see how hard it is for software to recognize text or pictures, how could an algorithm know where the red shopping cart sprite ends and the red tag sprite starts?

Comment: how about testing it via the dev tools of your browser

Answer (score 1):

Now if you are not adverse to uses SCSS/SASS, then I would highly recommend using Compass' [method](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).  It converts a folder of images into a sprite map and the creates classes that allows you to access these sprites.  This has proven to be the easiest way for me to work with sprites without worrying about all of the messy calculations.

If you can't do that, then what I have personally done, is create multiple small sprite maps.  For example, if I have an arrow that has a hover on/off state. It will stack it into one image and just create a class with a shifted background-position.